# Not able to import @WithAnonymousUser in Junit 4

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am unable to import @WithAnonymousUser annotaion in Junit 4. It is showing error in both corresponding import statement

> import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithAnonymousUser;

and annotation

> @WithAnonymousUser

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithAnonymousUser;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
public class SecurityUtilsTest {

Authentication authentication;

public void setup() {
    authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
    SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
    Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
}

@Test
@WithAnonymousUser
public void testIsAuthenticated_Failure() {
    boolean result = SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated();
    assertFalse(result);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Spring Security Test jar in your project. How you do this depends on how you are building your project.

If you are using maven, add this to your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```